# Python pytest - Mock local function variable

Tags: python, pytest

How can I mock the local variable of a function?
For example in below code, how do I assign value to username and host variables in pytest?

```
def get_ldap_groups():
    host= None
    username = None
    # call search method
    result = search(username, host)
```

Comment: You can't, because they're local variables in the function. That makes the function pretty useless anyway; why not make them _parameters_, then you can pass it whatever values you like?

Comment: Well, you can mock any function by replacing it with a `unittest.mock.Mock`. But the idea of mocking is to replace it in the context of a test and tailor the mock for that test. So, what is the test you need a mock for?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest passing in `host` and `username` as arguments to the function instead.

Not only will you be able to mock it but you will remove the responsibility of the function of having to create host and username dependencies for the search function (this is known as dependancy injection).

Why this is good is because it makes changing the function easier. Imagine you used it in multiple places, you would have to change it for each use instead of just having them read from an environment variable (for example). And of course the solution to your problem it solves; which it enables you to test your code easier.